# iphone program warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some code added in viewWillAppear;

> curr_rep_date = [tmpRptDt
>   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpYrVal]
>   withString:[NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"%d",(tmpCurrYearInt-2)]];

When I build, I get the following warning;

`warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *                }`

Also
`warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` for:

> replist_rptdt_dict =
>   PerformXMLXPathQuery(xmlData,
>   @"//XX/Period[@XX]");

Please let me know the reason.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think those are the right lines. The first warning is about an array vs a mutable array. Are you using an array somewhere near that string operation?

Comment: No, it is for the line I have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replist_rptdt_dict = PerformXMLXPathQuery(xmlData, @"//XX/Period[@XX]");
```

First, the Objective-C standard is to use camel cased english names for variables.  `replist_rptdt_dict` is confusing (it almost sounds like you have a list dictionary something what huh?).

> warning: incompatible Objective-C
>   types assigning 'struct NSArray *',
>   expected 'struct NSMutableArray *' }

This will happen if you have:

```
- (NSArray *) foo;
...
{
    NSMutableArray *bar = [someObject foo];
}
```

That is, `bar` is a more specific type -- a subclass -- than `foo`'s return value.  The compiler is complaining because your code is quite likely going to crash if you send, say, `removeObjectAtIndex:` to what is quite likely an immutable array.

Comment: But what if I want to use NSMutableArray and cannot control what gets returned i.e. an NSArray in this case ?

Comment: You can either create a new autoreleased NSMutableArray instance with [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[someObject foo]] or just cast is as a mutable array with (NSMutableArray *)[someObject foo].

Comment: You can't just cast it -- casting doesn't change the type, just what the compiler thinks the type is. Casting an NSArray to an NSMutableArray does *not* make it into an NSMutableArray.